# alert compare to flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails projects, sometimes I see the

```
redirect_to request.referrer, alert: "Some contents"
```

sometimes, I see

```
redirect_to request.referrer, flash: { error: "An error occured" }
```

What's the differences between two above use cases, and how can I understand and use them correctly

Comment: Hi, [another so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798791/what-is-the-difference-when-using-flash-error-alert-and-notice), I hope it can help you ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mauro. It really does